# How to use API with Python and pass data from a function to another one

Tags: python-3.x, api

I've started to learn Python during the lockdown and now I'd like to learn how to use API with Python.

I'd like to make a script that find the emails addresses of a company's employees and send them to an email campaign.

To do so, I've created **2 functions** :

**Function 1** => Finds all the email addresses of a company's employees (thanks to the Hunter API )

```
hunter = PyHunter('****************')
email_search = hunter.domain_search('stripe.com')


def clean_data():
    clean_list = []
    for email in email_search['emails']:
        value_dict = {}
        value_dict['email'] = email['value']
        clean_list.append(value_dict)
    return clean_list
```

This function returns a list of dictionaries with employees working emails :
[see the result here with stripe employees as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFqez.png)

But my issue comes from the second function who is supposed to send all the emails found in function 1, to an email campaign.

I don't know how to pass the result from function 1 to function 2

**Function 2** :

```
def send_lead_to_lemlist(email):

    api_key = "***********"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    for i in clean_data():
        data = { "email" : email}
        response = requests.post(f'https://api.lemlist.com/api/campaigns/ID_OF_MY_CAMPAIGN/leads/{email}', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('', api_key))
    return response.json()
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, are you trying to find a way to pass each value from `clean_list` after calling the first function into the second function?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i'm trying to do (sorry if it wasn't clear, english is not my native language :) )

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify the problem? You are already handling many results and passing many arguments to functions. What specific problem do you have passing the result from ``clean_data`` to ``send_lead_to_lemlist``?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think you need to set the result from clean_data to a variable first.

```
result = clean_data()
for i in result:
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need to do is call the function and place the result into a list. Then, loop over the list and call the second function for every value.

```py
emails = clean_data()
for email in emails:
    send_lead_to_lemlist(email)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Actually I just had to add 

   ` send_lead_to_lemlist **(email["email"])** ` since it was a dictionary. But I understand the logic now.

Comment: No Problem! Glad I helped!